# Expo audio recording webm

Tags: android, audio, react-native, audio-recording, expo

I am using expo and I am trying to record on android by using the webm output format ( `Expo.Audio.RECORDING_OPTION_ANDROID_OUTPUT_FORMAT_WEBM` ). My issue is that I have tried all the different encoders and none of them seem to work. I was expecting that the vorbis encoder would work ( `Expo.Audio.RECORDING_OPTION_ANDROID_AUDIO_ENCODER_VORBIS` ) but I always get back an exception

```
    {
        "tryLoc": "root",
        "completion": {
            "type": "throw",
            "arg": {
                "framesToPop": 1,
                "code": "E_AUDIO_RECORDING",
                "message": "Start encountered an error: recording not started",
                "stack": "Error: Start encountered an error: recording not started\n    at createErrorFromErrorData (blob:http://172.16.6.80:19001/96c6e3c7-f483-40d9-a3ad-7a7114468a07:2297:17)\n    at blob:http://172.16.6.80:19001/96c6e3c7-f483-40d9-a3ad-7a7114468a07:2249:27\n    at MessageQueue.__invokeCallback (blob:http://172.16.6.80:19001/96c6e3c7-f483-40d9-a3ad-7a7114468a07:2691:18)\n    at blob:http://172.16.6.80:19001/96c6e3c7-f483-40d9-a3ad-7a7114468a07:2436:18\n    at MessageQueue.__guardSafe (blob:http://172.16.6.80:19001/96c6e3c7-f483-40d9-a3ad-7a7114468a07:2604:11)\n    at MessageQueue.invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue (blob:http://172.16.6.80:19001/96c6e3c7-f483-40d9-a3ad-7a7114468a07:2435:14)\n    at http://172.16.6.80:19001/debugger-ui/debuggerWorker.js:72:58"
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the configuration that I am trying:

```
const recording = new Audio.Recording();
debugger;
await recording.prepareToRecordAsync({
  android: {
    extension: '.webm',
    outputFormat: Audio.RECORDING_OPTION_ANDROID_OUTPUT_FORMAT_WEBM,
    audioEncoder: Audio.RECORDING_OPTION_ANDROID_AUDIO_ENCODER_VORBIS,
    sampleRate: 44100,
    numberOfChannels: 2,
    bitRate: 128000
  },
  ios: {
    extension: '.wav',
    audioQuality: Audio.RECORDING_OPTION_IOS_AUDIO_QUALITY_MAX,
    sampleRate: 44100,
    numberOfChannels: 2,
    bitRate: 128000,
    linearPCMBitDepth: 16,
    linearPCMIsBigEndian: false,
    linearPCMIsFloat: false,
  },
});
```

Any ideas on why that happens and what is the appropriate encoder that I have to use?

Comment: Have you asked for permission before trying to record? `const { status } = await Expo.Permissions.askAsync(Expo.Permissions.AUDIO_RECORDING);` The const `status` will have the value `granted` if user authorizes audio recording.

Comment: @shimatai - yes I ask for the proper permissions. I am able to record with the `outputFormat: Audio.RECORDING_OPTION_ANDROID_OUTPUT_FORMAT_AAC_ADTS` and `audioEncoder: Audio.RECORDING_OPTION_ANDROID_AUDIO_ENCODER_AAC` but ideally i'd like to happen with webm.

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? My observation is that when I duplicate the HIGH quality definition in my code (with a modified name) and then reference the local definition, it is ignored and the low quality recording, 3gp vs m4a, results.

Comment: @FitterMan As far as I remember I couldn't find something that was working for me. I ended up creating a backend service, send whatever I was getting from ios and android and transcoding it by using AWS transcode. It wasn't ideal but was covering our needs.

Answer (score 1):

I am shooting in the dark, hope this may be of help.

**Enabling Audio and customizing Audio Mode**

> Expo.Audio.setIsEnabledAsync(value) Audio is enabled by default, but
>   if you want to write your own Audio API in a detached app, you might
>   want to disable the Expo Audio API.
>
> Arguments value (boolean) — true enables Expo Audio, and false
>   disables it.
>
> Returns A Promise that will reject if audio playback could not be
>   enabled for the device.
>
> Expo.Audio.setAudioModeAsync(mode) We provide this API to customize
>   the audio experience on iOS and Android.

These key value pairs may help as well.

- prepareToRecordAsync()
- stopAndUnloadAsync()

Audio Encoder list: (*I suggest using the Default just to debug it)

**audioEncoder**:

- Expo.Audio.RECORDING_OPTION_ANDROID_AUDIO_ENCODER_DEFAULT
- Expo.Audio.RECORDING_OPTION_ANDROID_AUDIO_ENCODER_AMR_NB
- Expo.Audio.RECORDING_OPTION_ANDROID_AUDIO_ENCODER_AMR_WB
- Expo.Audio.RECORDING_OPTION_ANDROID_AUDIO_ENCODER_AAC
- Expo.Audio.RECORDING_OPTION_ANDROID_AUDIO_ENCODER_HE_AAC
- Expo.Audio.RECORDING_OPTION_ANDROID_AUDIO_ENCODER_AAC_ELD
- Expo.Audio.RECORDING_OPTION_ANDROID_AUDIO_ENCODER_VORBIS

**Reference**: [expo.io](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/audio.html) (13/Feb/2018).

NOTE *.webm (Streamable only in Android 4.0 and above)

**Reference**: [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats.html) (13/Feb/2018).

Try use below code, high and low quality and android & ios:

```
  export const RECORDING_OPTIONS_PRESET_HIGH_QUALITY: RecordingOptions = {
  android: {
    extension: '.m4a',
    outputFormat: RECORDING_OPTION_ANDROID_OUTPUT_FORMAT_MPEG_4,
    audioEncoder: RECORDING_OPTION_ANDROID_AUDIO_ENCODER_AAC,
    sampleRate: 44100,
    numberOfChannels: 2,
    bitRate: 128000,
  },
  ios: {
    extension: '.caf',
    audioQuality: RECORDING_OPTION_IOS_AUDIO_QUALITY_MAX,
    sampleRate: 44100,
    numberOfChannels: 2,
    bitRate: 128000,
    linearPCMBitDepth: 16,
    linearPCMIsBigEndian: false,
    linearPCMIsFloat: false,
  },
};

export const RECORDING_OPTIONS_PRESET_LOW_QUALITY: RecordingOptions = {
  android: {
    extension: '.3gp',
    outputFormat: RECORDING_OPTION_ANDROID_OUTPUT_FORMAT_THREE_GPP,
    audioEncoder: RECORDING_OPTION_ANDROID_AUDIO_ENCODER_AMR_NB,
    sampleRate: 44100,
    numberOfChannels: 2,
    bitRate: 128000,
  },
  ios: {
    extension: '.caf',
    audioQuality: RECORDING_OPTION_IOS_AUDIO_QUALITY_MIN,
    sampleRate: 44100,
    numberOfChannels: 2,
    bitRate: 128000,
    linearPCMBitDepth: 16,
    linearPCMIsBigEndian: false,
    linearPCMIsFloat: false,
  },
};
```

**Reference**: [expo.io](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/audio.html) (13/Feb/2018).

Comment: I already use everything from the things above except for the `setIsEnabledAsync` because the application is not detached (yet). Is there a specific combination that can work? I can proved with the configurations that I provide to `Expo.Audio.setAudioModeAsync`, `prepareToRecordAsync` and `stopAndUnloadAsync`.

Comment: @stavros.zavrakas - use above code for a guide and see if it can work with your current setup.

Answer (score 0):

I spotted 2 problems. One was a mysterious issue with Expo where if I duplicated the high definition from the docs (source code) and used it locally, it would fail to register. I eventually went back to one of their examples that just did a simple start/stop of recording and worked forward, without a problem. I dug around a while and my conclusion is there is a sequence of initialization that has to be followed precisely to get the initialization of these settings to be accepted.

Once past the previous problem, I found that the following worked with Google Speech to Text. AWS indicates that they also accept AMR audio.

```
    android: {
      extension: '.amr',
      outputFormat: Audio.RECORDING_OPTION_ANDROID_OUTPUT_FORMAT_AMR_WB,
      audioEncoder: Audio.RECORDING_OPTION_ANDROID_AUDIO_ENCODER_AMR_WB,
      sampleRate: 16000,
      numberOfChannels: 1,
      bitRate: 128000,
    },
```